# React app deploy complete with firebase but i did not get a hosting url ? What i do now for successful deploy

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

[Why i did not get a hosting url? What I do now? See this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTbRA.jpg)

Comment: It says you have deployed a database instead of a react app!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you never configured Firebase Hosting, so `firebase deploy` only deploys the rules for your Realtime Database.

To get it to deploy the web site too, add a `hosting` section to your `firebase.json` file like the one shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#the_firebasejson_file) or run `firebase init hosting` and follow the prompts.